# Which is fine language for asp.net - C# or VB

Tags: asp.net

im going to digg asp.net deeply.To begin,i want to know which language has more features and advantages over the asp.net whether c# or VB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe they're roughly equal in what you can do with them. I'd say it'll probably comes down to personal preference, possibly based on your current experiences (if you're used to Java, you'll have a much easier time programming in C#, if you're used to Visual Basic, you'll probably prefer VB.net).

Answer (score 9):

They are almost the same. but i think you might find more resources using c# than using vb

Answer (score 5):

They're both fine for whatever you're likely to want to do. The features are pretty similar. Just pick whichever one you like the look of.

Answer (score 5):

They are equal in functionality (except some VERY minor details which you'll prolly never use/find out)

Both get compiled to the same CLR in the end.

VB.NET tends to be "easier" to read for non programmers with things like:

```
If True Then
'Do something
End If
```

While C# tends to be easier for programmers who have seen java or C++ or something, it looks and feels more like other programming langs where an if would look like:

```
if(true)
{
//Do Something
}
```

One massive difference is how ever that C# (like most languages) is case sensitive where VB.NET is not... also in C# you end a statement with a ";" where in VB.NET you just use a linebreak (return). Meaning in larger statements in VB.NET you have to "extend" the statement by using _ and &

There are some more nuances but in the end you can manage the exact same thing in both languages.

Answer (score 3):

The two have almost identical features.

Answer (score 1):

Features are the same, they both can use .NET Framework.

C# has somewhat more resources and it's syntax is shorter which is usually considered nicer. I've played with many languages including VB for a long time and now I just don't wish to touch it anymore because it's so verbose.

C# has also way more developers willing to work with it. Try hiring a VB dev... he he.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at both - at the end of the day, language syntax is relatively easy to pick up and its the framework that takes the bulk of the time involved in becoming comfortable in a language, which you can carry over between VB and C# in .Net.

I started out with VB.Net, switched to C# and now code day to day in both languages - although I will admit that all new projects get started in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to achieve the same stuff in both, but if you are new to programming and would like to try a language that will help you slide into others more easily I recommend c#, the syntax, data structures and library usage will prepare you for the small differences of other languages such as java, c/c++ and many more